# Parsing JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a JSON string as follows:

```
[{
    "ID":"1",
    "title":"New Product Launch",
    "fro":"Vitamin D",
    "summary":"New Vitamin D prodcut",
    "type":"image",
    "link":"http:\/\/www.foo.in\/upload\/image\/1.png",
    "detail":"13-11-2013",
    "fileSize":23763
},
{
    "ID":"2",
    "title":"New Product Launch",
    "fro":"Vitamin D",
    "summary":"New Vitamin D prodcut",
    "type":"image",
    "link":"http:\/\/www.foo.in\/upload\/image\/1.png",
    "detail":"13-11-2013",
    "fileSize":23763
}]
```

My code for parsing is as follows:

```
AnnouncementListObject resultsJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnnouncementListObject>(json); //line1

using (AnnouncementDataContext context = new AnnouncementDataContext(Con_String))
{
     AnnouncementData alData = new AnnouncementData();
     alData.announcementID = int.Parse(resultsJSON.ID);
             .
             .
             .
             .
       context.AnnouncementData.InsertOnSubmit(alData);
       context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class AnnouncementListObject
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string fro { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
    public object fileSize { get; set; }
}
```

But it throws error on line 1 where I deserialize the JSON data. I want to store this multiple data rows in database. I cannot use foreach loop here as JSON data is not enclosed under root node. Any help on how should I go about?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Will take care in future @JohnSaunders. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deserializing to a list like so

```
var resultsJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AnnouncementListObject>>(json); //line1
```

You're dealing with an array of JSON objects, but you're trying to cast it as a single object.

Comment: Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<App.AnnouncementListObject>' to 'App.AnnouncementListObject'`

Comment: @rishiJasapara, learn the basics of C# please. The type of your variable has to be matching to the returned data type...

Comment: @elgonzo: I am new to C#. Learning new things each day. I wasn't born with a golden spoon.

Comment: @rishiJasapara did you change it to `var`? or did you keep it as `AnnouncementListObject resultsJSON`?

Comment: I have kept it to `AnnouncementListObject resultJSON`

Comment: No you don't.  That's why you're getting the error.  As I mentioned, you're trying to cast an array into a single object. You can't do that.  You aren't reading a single instance of `AnnouncementListObject`, you're reading an array.  So, when you deserialize you HAVE to deserialize into a collection, not into a single object.  Change it to `var` and you'll end up with a list of objects.

Comment: Thank you @Smeegs for the wonderful break-through and more wonderful explanation to the method.